# Custom sort order for dataset after executing query?

Tags: delphi, sorting, dataset, delphi-2009, advantage-database-server

I want the result set of a database query to have a certain order. The information I want to order by is not contained in the database, but dynamically generated in code (so I cannot use `ORDER BY`).

Is there a way to sort a dataset *after* executing the database query? (I don't need indexed access but only want to iterate over all records.)

Comment: What type of dataset are you using?

Comment: The column you want to use to order is calculated? (using OnCalcFields)

Comment: @Cesar Currently there is no column, just an algorithm that can calculate a "weight" per record based on other data in the application. This weight is the sort criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility that shares similarities with Jens' answer (+1) but gets to the result in a slightly different fashion.

Given an existing table:

```
create table somedata (id integer, name char(20));
insert into somedata values ( 1, 'Tim' );
insert into somedata values ( 2, 'Bob' );
insert into somedata values ( 3, 'Joe' );
```

If you know the desired short order (either by processing the table or some query result from it), create a temp table that has some key value to match the desired rows from the original table and then the sort order data:

```
create table #sortorder( id integer, sortvalue integer );
```

Set the `sortvalue` field in the temp table to contain the desired order (it could be any sortable data type - doesn't have to be integer):

```
insert into #sortorder values ( 1, 15 );
insert into #sortorder values ( 2, 12 );
insert into #sortorder values ( 3, 5 );
```

Then generate the results with a join against the table that provides the sort order:

```
select sd.* from somedata sd, #sortorder so 
         where sd.id = so.id
         order by so.sortvalue;
```

Comment: I like this the most for large datasets, because the amount of data to transfer seems the least. For small datasets I would probably go for one of the CDS solutions.

Answer (score 3):

With a ClientDataset you are able to change the order after executing.
Settings IndexFieldNames sorts the dataset.

You can find information [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connecting_a_Client_Dataset_to_Another_Dataset_in_the_Same_Application) how to connect a clientdataset to another dataset in the same application.

```
  object DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = MyAdsQuery
    Left = 208
    Top = 88
  end
  object ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    ProviderName = 'DataSetProvider1'
    Left = 296
    Top = 88
  end
```

Comment: Good idea, but this would copy all my data to the CDS. So it is an option for small data sets.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the only reliable way to sort a dataset is to use `ORDER BY`.

I would:

1. Add a dummy `order_tag` field to your query.
2. Dump the results to temporary table.
3. Declare a cursor to iterate over the temporary table and set the `order_tag` using your custom logic and `UPDATE #temp_table` statements.
4. Select the data from the temporary table and order by the tag field.

Comment: That is on the server side, you can of course reorder on the client side as well, like some of the other answers suggest.

Comment: +1 I like the idea because I don't want to transfer all data at once to a CDS. Mark's answer goes one step further by not copying all data to a temp table.

Answer (score 2):

The main trick here would be to use an Internal calc field (FieldKind = fkInternalCalc) if they are supported by your TDataset sub-class. If they aren't, use a TClientDataset as an intermediate.

DFM:

```
object ClientDataSet1SortField: TIntegerField
  FieldKind = fkInternalCalc
  FieldName = 'SortField'
end
```

pas:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOConnection1.Open('dbuser', 'Hunter2');
  ClientDataSet1.SetProvider(ADOQuery1);  // set ClientDataset provider. This will create a TLocalAppServer provider "in the background"
  ClientDataSet1.Open;
  randomize;
  while not ClientDataSet1.Eof do
  begin
    ClientDataSet1.edit;

    ClientDataSet1SortField.AsInteger := random(100);
    // as ClientDataSet1SortField is fkInternalCalc it doesn't need to be in the query result set, but can be assigned and used for sorting
    ClientDataSet1.Post;
    ClientDataSet1.Next;
  end;
  clientdataset1.IndexFieldNames := 'SortField';
end;
```