# Sort a Delphi dataset

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, devart

I have an unsorted dataset (a TMSQuery from Devart) that I cannot sort using ORDER BY because I manipulate the records after opening the query so the order given by "ORDER BY" is lost.

I don't want to rewrite the whole logic so I should find a way to sort a dataset.

I can Assign the dataset to a TMemDataSet (TMemDataSet is a DevArt class) descendant (TVirtualTable from Devart), but after this how do I sort (I need to sort by a date field)?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903093/custom-sort-order-for-dataset-after-executing-query) but it doesn't relly contain the answer I am looking for.

Comment: From the blurb: "TMemDataset is a unique fully indexable memory table that work like a regular TTable except the records and indexes are all stored in RAM. [snip] Sorting the table is as easy as doing tbMem.OrderBy := 'Fld1;Fld2';" So that looks like your solution

Comment: I dont know aboout the component you are referring but for ADO you can use ADOQuery1.Sort := 'LastName ASC, DateDue DESC'

Comment: There is some misunderstanding because of me: TMemDataSet is a DevArt Class derived from TDataSet, while the one you mention is a 3rd part component that has the feature I need: http://www.shareit.com/product.html?productid=102196&language=FR&affiliateid=200067214

Comment: Uh, anyway by digging i found the INdexFieldNames property that does what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `IndexFieldNames` I solved the problem, it was what I waslooking for. Directly from the `TMSQuery` component:

```
MSQuery1.IndexFieldNames := 'EXECUTION_DATE'; //this does the job
```